# Escape json_encoded array for pg_copy_from command

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I'm importing huge amounts of data into Postgres with PHP's `pg_copy_from` command. This has worked fine for months, but now I need to add a JSON field to the command. What is the proper way to escape the output of a `json_encode` command for usage inside a `pg_copy_from` command? The field type is `json`.

I've tried `pg_escape_string`, but that only seems to escape single quotes properly?

The input data is considered **safe**, it does **not** come from users.

Example:

```
$myData = [
    implode(',', [
        'Hello World',
        ESCAPEFUNC(json_encode(['Hello' => 'World']))
    ])
];
pg_copy_from($conn, "my_table(my_string, my_json_data)", $myData,',');
```